# How can I use multiple gulpfile.js in an ASP.NET core project?

Tags: gulp, asp.net-core

The gulpfile.js in my ASP.NET core project is becoming larger, and want to break down the tasks into groups and move to different files. How can I have tasks in different JS files and accessing them in a single gulpfile.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to gulp [documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/split-tasks-across-multiple-files.md):

> If your gulpfile.js is starting to grow too large, you can split the tasks into separate files using one of the methods below.
>
> - Using [gulp-require-tasks](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/split-tasks-across-multiple-files.md#using-gulp-require-tasks)
> - Using [require-dir](http://gulp-require-tasks)

Moreover, those approaches are gulp specific, and work for any web project type, not only for ASP.NET Core.